# How to change jqGrid plusicon for subgrid position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/), which has a [subgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid) opening at the 3rd column of main grid. However, my plusicon are displaying in the beggining of each row (as 1st column).

Is there a way so that I can show the plusicon at 3rd column?

Comment: Editing for legibility, adding links.

Comment: Post your current source.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `remapColumnsByName` or `remapColumns` methods to reorder the position of the column, with "+" icons, used to expand/collapse the subgrid.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/changePositionOfSubgridColumn.htm), which uses

```
$("#list").jqGrid("remapColumnsByName", ["rn", "act", "name", "subgrid"], true);
```

to reorder first columns of the grid. See the below picture, where I marked in red color the icons of subgrid column.

[image]

The approach works on free jqGrid, because it's code is independent on the exact position of subgrid or multiselect column. The code of old jqGrid requires that subgrid column are placed at the beginning.